# Second Derivative of Cusp

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know the first derivative does not exist at a cusp.

Does this statement also hold for the second derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the second derivative is found by differentiating the first derivative. If the latter doesn't exist, then the former certainly cannot.